# Which application is currently using my camera on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, camera

I have an **A4Tech** camera on **Windows 10**.  It hasn't got an in-your-face led as such to indicate it's on.  I just noticed a blue haze but wasn't sure if it was a reflection or if the camera was on.  I used Zoom to confirm it was on and, it turned off when I exited Zoom.

**Question :** How can I tell which application is currently using the camera ?

There are many posts showing you which apps have access to it.  I want to know which one is currently using it.

Comment: https://www.onmsft.com/how-to/how-to-see-which-apps-are-using-your-webcam-in-windows-10

Comment: @Gantendo - that works when the camera is intentionally opened.  But right now, the camera is on, and none of the devices says **Currently in use**.  Surely there must be a history somewhere.

Comment: I searched the device name with process explorer, and nothing.  So, its possible that its an anomaly that the camera is on.  maybe nothing is using it.

Comment: Lens coating often has a slight blue shine. You cannot see whether the sensor is active.

Comment: Precisely, which is why it took me so long to realise that it was on.  There is a faint reflection-like spot on the lens, which tells me that its on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Which apps are allowed to or are using the webcam

As pointed out by @Gantendo from the link,

1. Open Settings
2. Click **Privacy** and select **Camera**
3. OR type in **Camera** in the search box and select **Camera Privacy Settings**.

This shows which apps have permission to use the camera and when they last used it as **Last accessed xxxxx**.  It will also show it is currently being used as **Currently in use**.  The list is divided into "Store Apps" and "Desktop Apps"

But

> Unfortunately, you can't necessarily rely on the contents of this screen. By virtue of their nature, desktop apps are able to access your camera hardware directly, bypassing Windows' regular APIs. This means that a malicious app could stream your camera feed without notifying Windows, so it won't show up in the list. Generally, most respectable programs will appear here, but Microsoft's own documentation warns of the possibility that some won't.

[How to see which apps are using your webcam in Windows 10](https://www.onmsft.com/how-to/how-to-see-which-apps-are-using-your-webcam-in-windows-10)

### How to identify which process is using the camera

1. Open Device Manager
2. Click on **Cameras** if it exists, otherwise click on **Imaging Devices**
3. Double click on the device
4. Select **Details** Tab
5. Select **Physical Device Object Name** in the drop down. (On mine it shows `\Device\0000006a`
6. Right click and Copy it
7. Launch Process Explorer from [Microsoft Sysinternals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)
8. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to open Search box
9. Paste from the clipboard
10. It will list all processes using that device
11. You can right-click and **Kill Process**

### Tracking processes accessing the camera

1. Open Registry Editor by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and typing `regedit`
2. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\webcam\`
3. If not found, try `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\webcam\`
4. Microsoft applications are saved as child keys, non-Microsoft applications are under **NonPackaged**
5. Click on the application
6. Each entry has two values **LastUsedTimeStart** and **LastUsedTimeStop**. Unfortunately, the values are stored in `FileTime`. It can be converted in most languages, I have not found an online tool yet.
7. To track in real-time, you can use **SysMon** with a `Registry Modification` event.

Information garnered from [medium.com](https://svch0st.medium.com/can-you-track-processes-accessing-the-camera-and-microphone-7e6885b37072) and tested on my PC.

Comment: 2 and 3 are the same string

Comment: The second reg key to check should be `HKEY_USERS\*\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\webcam\`  You need to find your profile id in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`

Comment: One can surely use the following for the second path? `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\webcam`

Comment: I have the Windows 10 camera app opened and it is showing me a video, but the process explorer does not find any according process for it ("\Device\000000dd").
Is there a special column which you have to enable in the process explorer to show/find that information?